# Authenticate graphcool-yoga with Passport

Tags: authentication, passport.js, graphql-js, graphcool, prisma

I am working on a project using graphcool-yoga with prisma bindings. Want to set up authentication using passport's Local, Bearer, Github and Twitter strategy. Here's what my graphql query looks like

```
user: (root, args, context, info) => {
const { id } = args;
if(!passport.authenticate('bearer')(context)){
    throw new Error('Not Authorised');
}
if (!id) {
  throw new Error('Id cannot be empty');
}

return context.db.query.user(
  {
    where: {
      id: id,
      active: true,
    },
  },
  info,
);}
```

My auth.js where I have implement my passport strategy for bearer token:

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as BearerStrategy } from 'passport-http-bearer';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

passport.use(new BearerStrategy((token, done) => {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) return done(null, err);
        if (decoded.sub) {
            done(null, decoded.sub || undefined);
        }
    });
}));
const middleware = express();
middleware.use(passport.initialize());
middleware.use(passport.session());
module.exports = {
    authMiddleware: middleware
};
```

and finally I used it as a middleware:

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: 'app/schema.graphql', // application api schema
  resolvers,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db
  }),
});
server.express.use(authMiddleware);
```

This is what I could write after reading various sources but is not working. Any correct and best way to do it?

Comment: what is the error message you receive?

Comment: No error message. it was just that I wasn't able to add authentication middleware to specific routes.

Comment: ok, were you able to solve the problem?  If not, please fix this post to include ALL relevant code, i'd be happy to help since i'm working on something similar right now.